# SOME css and images not loaded in spring boot run (IntelliJ)

Tags: java, css, spring-boot, intellij-idea, vaadin24

i am migrating my spring boot application (might be unrelated, just happened to pop up now) to spring boot 3 (and vaadin 24) and next to other differences i encountered a strange behaviour that never happened to me before:

when i run my application from IDE (normal spring boot application config with some custom environment variables) and call the website, a lot (but not all) static resources are not found (css, images).
Here's some infos and things i found out:

- all my static files are in /src/main/resource/static/**
- when i check my /target folder, i can see ALL static files exist in /target/classes/static/**
- However, for example /static/css/styleA.css will be loaded, while /static/css/styleB.css throws a 404 (**remember, BOTH exist in /target and are even in the exact same sub-folder**)
- this also happens, when i call the URL directly (instead of calling a website/view that imports the stylesheet or images)
- when i build the package with maven (mvn clean package spring-boot:repackage -Pproduction), and run the resulting war in console, all css and images can be loaded
- i already cleared the intellij cache with no success
- all my requests i did with developer options/network tab open and cache disabled
- my security config is attached at the end (special filter to allow a third parameter - client - for login)
- when i run

> getClass().getResource("/static/css/styleA.css"); 
> getClass().getResource("/static/css/styleB.css");

both paths point to the /target/classes/** folder.

i hope anyone can give me a hint or has an idea where this problem could come from. if you need more info just write into the comment, i try to deliver them as precisely as possible.

```
        http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
            .requestCache(c -> c.requestCache(new CustomRequestCache()))
            .addFilterBefore(filter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .authorizeHttpRequests(a ->
                    a.requestMatchers(SecurityUtils::isFrameworkInternalRequest,
                                    antMatcher("/"),
                                    antMatcher("/login"),
                                    antMatcher("/icons/**"),
                                    antMatcher("/sw.js"),
                                    antMatcher("/manifest.webmanifest"),
                                    antMatcher("/static/**"),
                                    antMatcher("/healthy/**"),
                                    antMatcher("/VAADIN/**"),
                                    antMatcher("/frontend/**"),
                                    antMatcher("/frontend-es5/**"),
                                    antMatcher("/frontend-es6/**")).permitAll()
                            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            )
            .formLogin(l -> l.loginPage("/login").permitAll())
            .headers(h -> h.frameOptions(FrameOptionsConfig::sameOrigin))
            .sessionManagement(m -> m.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.ALWAYS))
            .securityContext(c -> c.securityContextRepository(securityContextRepository()));

    return http.build();
```